# Import CSV files from multiple folders and append filename as additional column in python

Tags: python

I am trying to import multiple csv files into a single file without using pandas.  I have the following code.  However, I would like to be able to add the file name as a new column in the output file.  I have done it with Pandas but using Pandas for several hundred csv files in time consuming.  The code below is efficient for creating a single file.

```
import shutil
import glob, os
    os.chdir("D:\\DATA")
    allFiles = glob.glob("**/*.csv", recursive = True)
    with open('D:\\AllData.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
        for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
            with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
                shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the task line by line shouldn't take too long

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("D:\\DATA")
allFiles = glob.glob("**/*.csv", recursive = True)
data = []
for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
    with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
        read_lines = infile.readlines()
        read_lines = ['{0},{1}'.format(line.rstrip('\n'),fname) for line in read_lines]
        data += read_lines

with open('D:\\AllData.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n'.join(data))
```

Comment: Thanks this works.  Is it possible just to have the file name and exclude the Directory and .csv extension?

Answer (score 0):

The following works using os.path.basename.

filename = os.path.basename(fname).split('.')[0]
read_lines = ['{0},{1}'.format(line.rstrip('\n'), filename) for line in read_lines]